# error using statsmodels OLS: returning nan values

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a data set like:

```
Growth  NHSPSTY% Index  USURTOT Index   GLPFTOCI Index  CPTICHNG Index  NAPMPMI Index   RSTAXYOY Index  SAARTOTL Index  USASHVTK Index  CONCCONF Index  LEI TOTL Index  SPX Index   TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY BDIY Index  cry index   CO1 Comdty
Date                                                                
1998-03-31  4.1 7.5 4.7 0.121000    83.5325 52.9    2.9 -0.032258   0.404   133.80  88.9    0.455185    197.26  966 169.04  14.26
1998-06-30  3.8 9.8 4.5 0.125556    82.2970 48.9    4.5 0.154930    0.393   138.23  88.6    0.280973    204.65  856 152.58  13.38
```

I wanted to run a OLS regression but all the parameters returned all nan values.
And it warned:

```
/Users/jake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
/Users/jake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
/Users/jake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:1821: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)


coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
const   nan nan nan nan nan nan
NHSPSTY% Index  nan nan nan nan nan nan
USURTOT Index   nan nan nan nan nan nan
GLPFTOCI Index  nan nan nan nan nan nan
CPTICHNG Index  nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

My command:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(data.Growth,sm.add_constant(data.iloc[:,1:])).fit()
model.summary()
```

Comment: was it because missing values?

Comment: Missing values, `nan`, are not removed by default, except when using formulas. Use `missing='drop'` to have them removed by the model. But it's better to have clean data before using the models.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of getting only `nan` values in the output of OLS (linear regression) from statsmodels is `nan` / missing values in the provided data.

The handling of missing values by OLS can be changed via the `missing` argument.
From the documentation:

> missing str
>
> Available options are ‘none’, ‘drop’, and ‘raise’. If ‘none’, no nan
> checking is done. If ‘drop’, any observations with nans are dropped.
> If ‘raise’, an error is raised. Default is ‘none’.

[image]